# grey lines appearing on views in Xcode 7 for iOS9.0

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

When I run my code with Xcode 6.0 for iOS8x, everything works perfectly, but when I switch to Xcode 7 with iOS9.0, grey lines is appeared for on of the screens in the app.

I have purposefully kept the separator colour of the tableview in that screen to red colour in order to differentiate it with those unwanted grey lines. I also tried hiding the tableview separators but still those grey lines appear.

[image]

Comment: show code and screenshots...

Comment: If you've set the separator color on your table view to red, (if that's causing the red line on your screen" then it looks like you have more than one tableview being displayed on the screen).  This theory is bolstered by the fact that the gray separator lines are not aligned to what look like the cells of your view.    You might try calling recursiveDescription on the NSWindow of your app and look to see if you have an unexpected, stray table view.

Comment: @Scott Thompson : I have used exactly only one tableview. And this works perfectly for Xcode6.4 iOS8.x . I have not done any sort of coding for those grey lines. Its being appeared for only Xcode7.0 with iOS9.0

Comment: Why are you using a tableview if youre not using specific rows

Answer (score 1):

Those are TableViewCellSeparator, You can do this with the UITableView property separatorStyle. Make sure the property is set to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` and you're set.

**Objective-C**

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

**In Swift**

```
tableView.separatorStyle = .None
```

Comment: @Liji.Stephen I suggest you to check your app in device. so you will get actual idea. or try debug view hierarchy

Comment: yeah issue is solved... very wierd behaviour.. I just had to delete the main view and reinsert again